# How to refresh keyframe animation by click in js?

Tags: javascript, css-animations

I want make animation which started every click by button. It is work but only once. When pressed again nothing happens. Tried to remove and add the same class again. Did not help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <style type="text/css">
  body{
   margin: 0;
   padding:0;
   widht: 100%;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <style>
  @keyframes red-to-black {
   0% {background: rgba(150,0,0,100);}
   100% {background: rgba(0,0,0,100);}
  }
  .RedBack {
   animation: red-to-black 1s ease-out;
  } 
 </style>
 <div id="back" style = "background: black; width: 100vw; height:100vh;">
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('back').classList.add('RedBack');">Hello!</button>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remove the class after the animation ends. Then, when you add the class again, the animation will trigger again.

Here, I have removed the class after 1 second, because the animation duration is 1 second.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <style type="text/css">
  body{
   margin: 0;
   padding:0;
   widht: 100%;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <style>
  @keyframes red-to-black {
   0% {background: rgba(150,0,0,100);}
   100% {background: rgba(0,0,0,100);}
  }
  .RedBack {
   animation: red-to-black 1s ease-out;
  } 
 </style>
 <div id="back" style = "background: black; width: 100vw; height:100vh;">
  <button onclick="onClick()">Hello!</button>
 </div>
    <script>
        function onClick() {
            document.getElementById('back').classList.add('RedBack');
            setTimeout(() => {
               document.getElementById('back').classList.remove('RedBack');
            }, 1000)
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanx, can you explain why this does not work?
  <button onclick="
   if (document.getElementById('back').classList.contains('RedBack')) {
    document.getElementById('back').classList.remove('RedBack');
   }
   document.getElementById('back').classList.add('RedBack');
  ">Hello!</button>